# Why the specified classpath doesn't find the extended class?

Tags: java, classpath, javac, cp

I was messing around with classpaths etc. And there is something that I totally don't get...

Let's assume we have two files in a dir structure as follows:

```
[current dir]
|
org
|
amigo
|
|---A.class
|---B.java
```

Class A:

```
package org.amigo;
public class A {}
```

Class B:

```
package org.amigo;
public class B extends A {}
```

So far so good... Now, being in the `current dir` we invoke

```
javac org\amigo\B.java
```

This compiles the class just fine. Next let's try

```
javac -cp . org\amigo\B.java
```

This works as well. But... when we try to run

```
javac -cp .:org org\amigo\B.java
```

we get a:

```
cannot find symbol
symbol: class A
public class B extends A {
                       ^
1 error
```

Soooooo.... my question is - how come this doesn't work?

(Of course we could replace `-cp .:org` with `-cp .:[any dir]` and still get the same result.)

As I understand (do I?... -_-) the `-classpath` option, it just let's us specify in which directories to search for the required class. So if the A.class is present in one of those directories shoulnd't it work anyway? I mean - just the `-cp .` option worked!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On Windows the path separator is ';'. So instead of saying "look in . and in org", you are explicitly stating that the path the VM should look for classes is ".:org", which doesn't exist. But at the same time that forbids the VM to look in the current directory, and thus it does not find the classes.